# lenovo p70 contacts lost after upgrade

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, stock-android, 5.1-lollipop, ota-update

after an ota upgrade of lenovo p70 from version kitkat 4.4.4 to lollipop 5.1 no contacts are visable

thanks
Msadek

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! We will need much more information to give recommendations here. Please [edit] your question and add: where are no contacts visible? What steps to reproduce? Where there any errors shown during upgrade? Are your contacts synced with Google (or any other service) – and if so, are they visible there? Is your device still able to access that service / Google Play Store (i.e. is the account still configured)? Did anything else go missing after the upgrade (could it e.g. be the device was [factory-reset](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/factory-reset/info))?

Comment: the problem was resolved when i removed some installed applications

Comment: the issue was not in the sync but it was related to the viewing of the contacts, even the call log was empty and received calls were not in the log

Comment: Mind to write up an answer of what you did to solve your issue, naming the culprits which blocked your view? That would be helpful to others sitting in the same boat. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

the problem was resolved when i removed some installed applications

i am not sure exactly which application was the reason as i removed many applications

i even tried many 3rd party contacts and dialer apps, but even those either worked for some time then stopped or didn't work at all

the issue was not in the sync but it was related to the viewing of the contacts, even the call log was empty and received calls were not in the log

thanks
Msadek